# How to Sanitize PDF with a opensource Java tool ( like PDFBox)?

Tags: java, security, pdf, sanitization, malware

I am trying to enhance security of a file upload segment in Spring based web application.

It uses a antivirus to do virus screening before upload, However it is additionally required to sanitize the files or restrict the files with active contents(javascript, autoaction) from being uploaded .

Allowed file formats are XLS, DOCX, PDF along with few image formats.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a CDR product. There are plenty of options out there - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Disarm_%26_Reconstruction

Comment: Or do you want to _implement_ a CDR tool using PDFBox as base library?

Comment: I remember a discussion on the pdfbox users mailing list years ago, use the search feature and search for "Roberto Nibali". IIRC we discussed the many possibilities where there could be JS content :-(

Comment: I was looking for a light weight implementation to detect and block PDF files with ActiveContent. Implementation on top of any Opensource library should do

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might need it later. This seems like a good starting point.

(Even though archived) DocBleach project has the implementation to detect malicious content and to sanitize the file. it also supports other office formats. It is build on top of pdfbox.

https://github.com/docbleach/DocBleach

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).